# Unable to scan all the elements of the string array using scanner in java

Tags: java, string

I am unable to scan all the elements of the string array in Java. I don't know what is the error.. please help

I'm unable to scan the first element of the array.its not even showing an error.

```
import java.util.*;

public class uhu {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hit n");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        int n = sc.nextInt();//scan the size of the array
        String[] str=new String[n];
        System.out.println("Enter elements");
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) //scanning the elements 
        {
            str[i]=sc.nextLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //printing all the elements
        {
            System.out.println(str[i]);
        }
    } finally {
        if (sc != null)
            sc.close();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: For one thing, you are not starting the first loop from `0`. And 2nd, please be specific about the issue. How is it not working. What output you get? What you expected?

Comment: this is working fine for me, what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
System.out.println("Enter elements");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //scanning the elements 
{
    str[i]= sc.next();
}
```

start from i=0 and use next() instead of nextLine().

In case you want to read whole lines then a BufferedReader will do the job, here in our case Scanner nextLine() is skipping the last line or taking a blank line as input at the end.

Use BufferedReader to get your job done.

```
System.out.println("Hit n");
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
try {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine());//scan the size of the array
    String[] str=new String[n];
    System.out.println("Enter elements");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //scanning the elements 
    {
        str[i]= buf.readLine();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //printing all the elements
    {
        System.out.println(str[i]);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (buf != null)
        buf.close();
}
```

Comment: Use BufferedReader to read whole lines, Scanner.next() will only read a word.